# NextJS 13 crashes my computer Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, crash, nodejs

So I recently updated from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 (mainly to remove the SDA3 Crypt). I'm a an thus far except for one issue I keep facing. Everytime I run next dev, my laptop goes to 1 fps and eventually crashes. This was not an issue for me on 20.04. Anyone else have this issue or know a fix? It's not a beefy computer but I never used to have this issue on 20.04 which is where my shock is coming from:

Here are some relevant details:

**Hardware Model:** Lenovo Lenovo V15 G1 IML
**Memory:** 12.0 GiB
**Processor:** Intel® Core™ i3-10110U CPU @ 2.10GHz × 4
**Graphics:** Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
**Disk Capacity:** 1.0 TB
**OS Name:** Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
**OS-Type:** 64-bit
**GNOME Version:** 42.9
**Windowing System:** Wayland

**Node Version:** 18.16.0
**NPM Version:** 9.5.1
**NextJS Version:** 13.4.8

VS Code Details:
**Version:** 1.79.1
**Commit:** 4cb974a7aed77a74c7813bdccd99ee0d04901215
**Date:** 2023-06-12T16:17:13.990Z
**Electron:** 22.5.7
**Chromium:** 108.0.5359.215
**Node.js:** 16.17.1
**V8:** 10.8.168.25-electron.0
**OS:** Linux x64 6.2.0-37-generic